# Is there a way to get github action workflow log while it is running

Tags: github-actions, intellij-plugin

I am developing an [intellij plugin for github actions](https://github.com/cunla/ghactions-toolbar) and I am able to download logs for completed workflow runs. However, while the workflow run is still in progress the [rest-api for downloading logs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#download-workflow-run-attempt-logs) does not work (returns 404).

Is there a different API I can use to view logs of running GitHub actions workflow?